# Difference between 丸い and 円い

Tags: word-choice, kanji

Both come up with the same reading and definition in Jisho.org (round/circular), and both are listed as common words. Is there any preference between the two or should I simply learn both as interchangeable?

Comment: This jisho has the info: http://wwwjdic.org (Jim Breen's WWWJDIC).  Both spellings are marked with a P which means both are preferred.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

丸い generally refers to spherical objects like a globe.

円い generally refers to circular objects like a circle drawn on a page. Perhaps also a physical object which is flat and round in shape (a 円 (yen) coin for example)

Comment: Thank you! I seem to remember now seeing that somewhere, but Jisho wasn't much help to me.

Comment: It should be noted that you can write `丸く描く` but you wouldn't write `円く描く` even if drawing a circle on a page.

Comment: @Jesse I agree that 丸く might be more common, but do you have evidence that 円く is wrong? A similar point, though: to write まる, you would use 丸 even if it means a circle, maybe to avoid confusion with 円{えん} which is a word meaning circle by itself, whereas there's no 丸{がん} by itself AFAIK.

Comment: @dainichi: Unfortunately, I don't have any evidence, so maybe I shouldn't say it is wrong, just more common as you mention. Also, you make a good point about まる only can be written as 丸, that is the reason we have 日の丸 and not 日の円 because the 訓読み for まる is 丸 only.

Answer (score 5):

円 is usually read えん, and reading it まる sounds like ateji, and is less common. 丸い　should be used.

Comment: +1: I tend to agree, just remember there are certain "special" words that use `円い` instead, for example `円い月` and `円い人柄`.